# How can I use two ng-repeats to iterate through an array that might have a different length?

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat and another ng-repeat inside that like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4]">
    <div ng-repeat="j in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]" ng-init="row=qs[i * 10 + j + 1]'">
          <div ng-click="getQuestion(row.number)">
            {{ row.number }}  
          </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The code iterates through 50 members of the array `qs` which is defined on my $scope in the controller loaded there. The code above nicely creates 5 rows of ten `<div>`s to hold details from each array element.

It's possible however that the qs array could have just 2 or perhaps 12 or 20 or any number of elements. If it was 2 elements I would want to have one row of two `<div>`s.  If it was twelve I would want to have one row of 10 `<div>`s and one row below that of two `<div>`s.

Is there a way that I could make this code more flexible so that it could cope with a different array lengths? In particular I realize that for example I could take the array length and if it was 25 then I know I would have to have my ng repeat of i go through `[0,1,2]` but how can I create the `[0,1,2]` from 25 ?

Comment: Use a controller, place your arrays in the controller as scoped properties and then you will have `.length`.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe my question was not clear I only have one array called qs and it's length would be qs.length. I just need to do this the one time with the array qs.

Comment: Can't you just iterate through the qns array why all this fuss

Comment: @psl - I'm being asked to create the <div>s in rows of ten. The code now works good for an array with 50 elements. I am just not sure how I could adapt it to work for an array with a smaller number.

Comment: Map your inital array to nest the data. Seems like your issue is data structure not how to use ng-repeat. Provide a demo with sample data

Comment: @Alan why don't you convert your view model accordingly in your controller rather than doing it in the view? It is kind of unclear, do you have a demo?

Comment: @charlietfl - I can't really change the data in qs as that's used by other parts of the code. Everything works as is already but I just need some way  to not have to enter in [0,1,2] etc and rather have this done based on the number of elements in the array divided by ten.

Comment: @psl - Yeah I think it could be done differently but the only part of the code not working the way I need is [0,1,2,3,4] and [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] which are hard coded.  Maybe there's a way to do it using javascript but I am not sure.

Comment: @Alan if you want the array of specified length then you could probably use a filter something like this `.filter('range', function() {
        return function(input, range) {
          if (range < 1) return [];
          return Array.apply(null, {
            length: range
          }).map(Number.call, Number);
        }
      })` and set it up as `<div ng-repeat="i in [] | range:qs.length/10">`

Comment: `used by other parts of the code` doesn't necessarily justify bad structure but it also doesn't mean you can't map it to other structures and still maintain inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a simple filter to generate array based on provided length.

```
 .filter('range', function() {
    return function(input, range) {
      if (range < 1) return [];
      return Array.apply(null, {
        length: range
      }).map(Number.call, Number);
    }
  });
```

and just use it as:-

```
  <div ng-repeat="i in []|range:qns.length/10">
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
$scope.count = 100;
})
  .filter('range', function() {
    return function(input, range) {
      if (range < 1) return [];
      return Array.apply(null, {
        length: range
      }).map(Number.call, Number);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="i in []|range:count/10">
    Hey
  </div>
</div>
```